# Сформировать sql-запрос с отступом

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Исходные значения:

```
$limit = 5;
$page = intval($page);
$offset = ($page - 1) * self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT;
```

Есть следующий запрос:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = '1' AND category_id = '$categoryId' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ".$limit.' OFFSET'. $offset);
```

Ошибка идет после `LIMIT`. Как правильно сформировать запрос, который выводит записи с ограниченным количеством и отступом, который храниться в переменной `$offset`

Comment: сделать так, чтобы у переменных **были значения**

Comment: `' OFFSET'. $offset); ` и тут еще пробела не хватает

Comment: У них и так есть значения

Comment: `Как мне правильно сформировать запрос` - cформировать его в переменной, и перед передачей его mysqli_query вывести на просмотр. Тогда будет предмет для разговора. `Ошибка идет после LIMIT` Цитируйте сообщение об ошибке, а не Ваши "мысли по поводу".

Answer (score 3):

Запросы, в которых участвуют переменные, надо формировать с помощью **подготовленных выражений**. Это **гарантирует** отсутствие ошибок, вызываемых передаваемыми данными, не говоря уже о защите от инъекций.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = '1' AND category_id = ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?"; 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sii", $categoryId,$limit,$offset);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```